# Elasticsearch php error

Tags: elastica, elasticsearch

I am getting the following error when I am trying to insert data

```
{"error":"MapperParsingException[failed to parse [Pub]]; nested:
MapperParsingException[failed to parse date field [false], tried both date format 
[dateOptionalTime], and timestamp number with locale []]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: \"false\"]; ","status":400}
```

Comment: From this I can understand that you are trying to index a document containing  date field whose format is incorrect. This might be happening because you have defined the mapping for a particular field as date and now you are trying to index a value  some other data type than date. Can you post the document you are trying to index and the mapping definitiom of your index?

Comment: can you share your Query DSL?

Comment: The issue is solved I was making mistake in date format.